# anchor taking user to root directory?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, anchor

I have 3 files, packages.php, index.php and .htaccess.

[packages](https://paste.lucko.me/sd9mbiYjTH) (hastebin is down for me), [index](https://paste.lucko.me/WmtIpIS7Gx) and [.htaccess](https://paste.lucko.me/oG7WSzFGCj). This is live [here](https://www.piggypiglet.me/minepos/admin/). Currently, index works as you can see by the no .php extension and the extra slash. However, if you go into Packages -> Create or Manage Packages, it takes you to piggypiglet.me/packages. I have no clue why this is? It also redirects you there when trying to manually open https://www.piggypiglet.me/minepos/admin/packages. I've tried changing the anchor to ./packages but that didn't fix it. I'm really at a loss here, I have no clue what's causing it. Also, the .php extensions are necessary as I'll be using php in the files as soon as I get this issue fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link to admin/packages currently works fine for me. Did you solve it? Otherwise I suspect your browser might be caching the redirect from some previous version ( [R=permanent] ). Another thing that comes to my mind is trying to play with RewriteBase.

Comment: Works for me too, so maybe a cache issue (or maybe fixed)? Assuming the site and `.htaccess` file are in the document root then `RewriteBase` should not be necessary here.